# What are Django context processors?

Tags: django

I am struggling with these concepts. For example, I have this view function

```
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,status='published',p__year=year,p__month=month,p__day=day,status='published',)
    return render(request,'blog/post/detail.html',{'post': post})
```

As I understand, function will take request object as parameter, the template path and the variables to render the given template. Until now it is OK. But now comes template context processor and the magic behind the scene. From [djangoproject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)

> The `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting is a tuple of callables –
>   called context processors – that take a request object as their
>   argument and return a dictionary of items to be merged into the
>   context

What are they actually doing? They will expose data inside templates, are there any limitations regarding the input data?

Comment: There is an example of one in the documentation, which also lists all of the default context processors that you could go and have a look at. It's not clear what you're asking - what are they (this is answered in the quote you've posted), what are they doing (see their various implementations) or are there limitations (what do you mean by this)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe For example request object could be any Python object?I have come across,if request.method == 'POST'.Type(request) does not have constrains?

Comment: What do you mean *"any Python object"*? The request object will be [a request object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest).

Comment: Instance of HttpRequest class?

Comment: But now you seem to have switched your question from context processors to request objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking how `context_processors` work, right?

You can see django source code - it's pretty amazing and well organized.

It's best way to tracking source code, but I try to explain a bit.

First, if you use `render` (or maybe `render_to_response` ) for almost every view. (even in CBV).

it return `HttpResponse` with content - which uses `loader.render_to_string`. for easy understanding, I attach `render_to_response` below.

```
def render_to_response(template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None):
    """
    Returns a HttpResponse whose content is filled with the result of calling
    django.template.loader.render_to_string() with the passed arguments.
    """
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, using=using)
    return HttpResponse(content, content_type, status)
```

And then you can find out `loader.render_to_string` that takes `context`. It returns `template.render(context, request)`

```
class Template(object):

    def __init__(self, template, backend):
        self.template = template
        self.backend = backend

    @property
    def origin(self):
        return self.template.origin

    def render(self, context=None, request=None):
        context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)
        try:
            return self.template.render(context)
        except TemplateDoesNotExist as exc:
            reraise(exc, self.backend)
```

As you see above, it define `context` using `make_context`. In there, django automatically add some context's that you define in `settings.py`.

```
def make_context(context, request=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Create a suitable Context from a plain dict and optionally an HttpRequest.
    """
    if context is not None and not isinstance(context, dict):
        raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)
    if request is None:
        context = Context(context, **kwargs)
    else:
        # The following pattern is required to ensure values from
        # context override those from template context processors.
        original_context = context
        context = RequestContext(request, **kwargs)
        if original_context:
            context.push(original_context)
    return context
```

It uses `RequestContext` that call processors from settings and bind it to context.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/template/context/#RequestContext), you can check full `RequestContext` code.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer.I am new to Django. Does render method automates HTML escaping by default?

Comment: Yes. there's `autoescape` settings in `DjangoTemplates` options. It defauls to True and you can chnage to False. Try checking here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django)

Answer (score 5):

for every django view, either it is function based view or class based view you will return context when you render the html as you mentioned. if all you want is a simple page with some data to show its all fine. but if you are looking to get some specific data on every page, say suppose user details, or menu etc. then it is hard to insert this data in each and every view you write. that is why you have context processors, you can write a simple class/function which returns a dictionary that should be merged with context of each view. now your menus and user data will be rendered seamlessly